# ROOT_URLCONF error in Django

Tags: django

I have this in my urls.py:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'sdaps_web.urls'
```

When visiting url localhost:port I get following error:

```
'AdminSite' object has no attribute 'root'
```

URLS config:

```
url(r'^admin/(.*)', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^', include(views)),
url(r'^', include(sdaps_ctl.views)),
url(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
url(r'^$', direct_to_template,
        { 'template': 'index.html' }, 'index'),
```

I am running Django 1.6.1 ... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `admin.site.urls`, not the `admin.site.root`:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Comment: Now I am getting TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/ at Exception Value: 
registration/login.html

Comment: `django-registration` comes without any templates.  You have to write them by yourself.

Comment: I have them. Just do not know where to put them.

Comment: Create the `registration` directory in the `templates` dir (alongside with your `index.html`) and put the `login.html` template into this `templates/registration` directory.

Comment: I already have that file in dir, still error:

"root@mmm:/opt/webapp/sdaps/sdaps_web/templates/registration# ls
login.html"

Comment: And your `index` page works well?  `index.html` template loads without errors?

Comment: This is the only error I am seeing at the time. I previosly had problems with admin, but that has been taken care off..

Comment: Did you tried to open the home page? Did the `index.html` rendered?  Had you set up the TEMPLATE_DIRS setting?

Comment: After visiting IP:HOST i am immediatelly redirected to http://IP:HOST/accounts/login/?next=/surveys

Comment: And what about the TEMPLATE_DIRS?